# php Preg_match pattern to solve

Tags: php, preg-match

i have the following pattern that i am trying to solve with preg_match

```
  http://www.1.com/images/001/001/001/1.jpg
    http://www.2.com/images/002/002/002/2.jpg
    http://www.3.com/images/003/003/003/3.jpg
    http://www.4.com/images/004/004/004/4.jpg
    http://www.5.com/images/005/005/005/5.jpg
    etc.
```

i need to get only everything that goes after IMAGES and ends before last slash, for example 002/002/002

Hope i could explain well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use preg_match_**all** in this case.

```
<?php

$in = 'http://www.1.com/images/001/001/001/1.jpg
    http://www.2.com/images/002/002/002/2.jpg
    http://www.3.com/images/003/003/003/3.jpg
    http://www.4.com/images/004/004/004/4.jpg
    http://www.5.com/images/005/005/005/5.jpg';

if (preg_match_all('~images/(.*?)\.jpg~i', $in, $matches)) {

    print_r ($matches[1]);

} else {
    echo 'NOT FOUND';
}
```